# Unknown destination during deep link

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have a following navigation graph named `global_graph`:

```
A -> B -> C
```

All A, B and C are fragment. In the `C` layout I have a `<fragment/>` with attribute `app:navGraph`set to a different navigation graph. In case I open the app directly there is no issue with navigation. But when i try to open it from deeplink the app crashed every time I try to navigate to `C`, including all following scenarios:

1. Set a deeplink destination to `C`
2. Set a deeplink destination to `A` or `B` then navigate to `C`. App crashed when navigating from `B` to `C` happend.

Below is the error stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unknown destination during deep link: com.example.ltvlu.navitaion_jetpack:id/global_graph
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.handleDeepLink(NavController.java:588)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:488)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:425)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:235)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1418)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1195)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1078)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:117)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2408)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:648)
```

This is my navigation component dependencies:

```
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha09'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha09'
```

I just wonder if this is a library bug and is there any way to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121340440) of the Navigation library when using multiple NavHostFragments.